Is there automatically no magnetic field if there are no currents and $\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}=0$?
I recently came across an exercise that went like this:
Prove that if $$\dfrac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}=0=\vec{j},$$ then $$\vec{E}=-\nabla \Phi$$ only using the four Maxwell equations
$$\nabla \cdot \vec{E}=\frac{\rho}{\varepsilon_0} , \qquad \nabla \times \vec{E}= -\frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t}$$
$$\nabla \cdot \vec{B}=0, \qquad \nabla \times \vec{B} - \frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial \vec{E}}{\partial t}= \mu_0 \vec{j}.$$
The exercise is equivalent to showing $$\nabla \times \vec{E}=0$$ because we are assuming we are in a topologically nice region.
As someone pointed out in the comments of a previous question, there are setups with $\vec{j}=0=\dfrac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}$ in which $$\nabla \times \vec{E} \neq 0 \Rightarrow \dfrac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t} \neq 0 \Rightarrow \vec{B} \neq 0,$$ e.g. a linearly polarized plane wave superposed on electrostatic field of $\rho$. My understanding was always that if $\vec{j}=0=\dfrac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}$, there are no moving charges or currents, meaning that there is also no $\vec{B}$ field. Is this understanding of mine fundamentally wrong?

Even if you do not have currents and the charge is stationary, you can, however, have an electromagnetic wave which passes through your laboratory, which makes $\vec{E}$ not electrostatic.
It is sufficient to avoid that situation, and Maxwell's equations do the job.
To prove it, notice that Maxwell equations imply, in particular, the inhomogeneous wave equation for $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{B}$. In particular:
$$\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} \vec{B}(t, \vec{x}) - \Delta_{\vec{x}}\vec{B}(t, \vec{x})= \mu_0\vec{J}(t,\vec{x})\:.\tag{1}\label{eq:1}$$
If we impose that $\vec{J}(t, \vec{x})\equiv \vec{0}$ as assumed, but also that there is no wave of magnetic field in the space at the initial time,
$$\vec{B}(0,\vec{x})\equiv \vec{0}\:, \quad \partial_t \vec{B}(0,\vec{x})\equiv \vec{0},$$ the only solution of \eqref{eq:1} is
$$\vec{B}(t, \vec{x})\equiv \vec{0}$$
on account of known theorems on the initial value problem of the wave equation.
At this juncture, we can exploit the second equation you wrote, which boils down to
$$\nabla \times \vec{E}(t,\vec{x})= \vec{0}.$$
This equation implies that, at fixed $t$, (in a simply connected open domain)
$$\vec{E}(t, \vec{x})= \nabla \Phi(t, \vec{x})\tag{2}\label{eq:2}\:.$$
Inserting this result in the first equation you wrote, we have
$$\Delta_{\vec{x}} \Phi(t, \vec{x}) = \frac{1}{\epsilon_0}\rho(\vec{x})\:,$$
where I made explicit your hypothesis of stationary charge.
As a consequence:
$$\Delta_{\vec{x}} \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Phi(t, \vec{x}) = 0\:.$$
If we now assume that the electric field (the gradient of $\phi$) vanishes at infinity in a sufficiently fast way (with its temporal derivative) at every time (if we are working in a domain that is not the whole space, what I am about requiring should hold on the boundary of the domain), the equation above has the solution
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Phi(t, \vec{x}) \equiv f(t)\:,$$ for some function of the only temporal variable. Therefore, integrating it,
$$\Phi = \Phi_0(\vec{x}) + g(t).$$
In summary, inserting this result in \eqref{eq:2}, we conclude that $\vec{E}$ is electrostatic:
$$\vec{E}(\vec{x}) =  \nabla_{\vec{x}} \Phi_0(\vec{x}).$$

You are correct in that magnetic fields can only be initially generated by charges that are moving. However, once the field has been generated, it may propagate out in space as an electromagnetic wave, even if the original source is removed, and because of that you certainly can have a magnetic field without any sources present.

The answer to this relies on quantum mechanics. In quantum mechanics, you have elementary particles that have an intrinsic magnetic dipole moment, independent of the movement of the particle. This is similar of how the electron can have an intrinsic charge.
If we consider only classical mechanics, you could still have magnets with permanent magnetic moments which produce a field without moving. Of course if you examine what produces those fields you are forced to explain them using quantum mechanics per Bohr-van Leeuwen theorem.

On the magnetic field:
In Special Relativity, what is called "magnetic field" depends on your Lorentz frame. Thus, even if there is no current, but there is a non-trivial charge distribution, after a Lorentz boost, there would be a magnetic field. Therefore, we must fix a specific Lorentz frame in order to discuss whether the magnetic field is vanishing (independently of the electric field).
It depends on your boundary conditions.
Maxwell's equations are a system of PDEs, so the solutions depend on the boundary.

Consider a finite region in space devoid of any charge or current. In general, there could still be a non-vanishing magnetic field due to EM-waves coming from the outside. E.g., radiation caused by a dipole outside the region.

Consider your finite region to be surrounded by a grounded ideal Faraday cage. In this case, the boundary conditions imply that no EM-waves are coming in from the outside.

Finally, consider the whole of space (and time). Could there be a non-vanishing magnetic field if there is no current (or even no charge) in the universe? Mathematically, the difference in this scenario is that we don't have a boundary any more. However, $\mathbb R^3 \times \mathbb R$ is not compact, so sloppily speaking, we still have a boundary at infinity. Thus, we can have EM-waves with non-vanishing magnetic fields that originate from infinity.


Since Maxwell's equations are conformal, one may also consider the conformal compactification of Minkowski. Doing this, the EM-waves in Minkowski space are determined by the boundary conditions on $i^-$ and $\mathscr I^-$.

